# Destroy instance of a Fragment/trigger onDestroy with Navigation library

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack

I am using Navigation library and my use case is preserve Fragment state on back press which I achieve by returning already inflated binding in onViewCreated as when changing fragments Navigations seems not to destroy already existing instance of this fragment the actual view variable exists when you navigate there back or up.

But I also have a use case when I need to recreate this Fragment instance so I expect to have a way to call onDestroy() for that fragment. But I don't see any api for removing/obtaining existing in the backstack instances.

So my question is **how to get an existing instance of a Fragment from nav back stack and destroy it or just remove it by calling nav controller api**.

some code:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), mViewModelFactory)
            .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        parseNavigationExtra()
        return if (::mBinding.isInitialized) {
            mBinding.root
        } else {
        //create new binding
}
```

so when I call this action I still get the old binding root as the variable is still present.

```
  <action
        android:id="@+id/clearBackStack"
        app:destination="@+id/mainFragment"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/mobile_navigation"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<Fragment> fragments = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();          
Fragment lastFragment = fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(emptyDialog);
```

Comment: thanks but i am using Navigation library from jetpack. This code is good if you're using fragment manager which i am not. also just fyi this code has multiple npe places and possible out of bounds exception too.

Comment: I am too using Navigation, and I got same problem as you. This code helps

Comment: you can be using fragment manager along with navigation but I am concerned it may enter a weird condition accessing the graph through the manager. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

changes in the navigation library since 2.1.0

NavBackStackEntry: You can now call NavController.getBackStackEntry(), passing in the ID of a destination or navigation graph on the back stack. The returned NavBackStackEntry provides a Navigation-driven LifecycleOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner (the same returned by NavController.getViewModelStoreOwner()), and SavedStateRegistryOwner, in addition to providing the arguments used to start that destination.

So the plan is to use the new api to see what is available for NavBackStackEntry.